# html ordered list attributes "start" and "type" not working in external css

Tags: css, html

I need to make a list in table of 3*2, with one row of th. All the css should be externally described, and all other css is working except ol attributes: start and type.

I tried several ways just to test:
1.
html code:

```
<td class=cell3> //cell3 is another css I defined for td
    <ol>
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li>ol1 - item3</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

CSS code:

```
ol{
type: "I";
color: red;
start: "3"; }
```

2.
html code:

```
<td class=cell3>
    <ol class = r3c1>
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li>ol1 - item3</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

css code:

```
ol.r3c1{
    type: "I";
    color: red;
    start: "3";
}
```

For both way, the "color" attribute works, but type and start aren't.. why is that?(both type and start worked if I enter them as in-line style.)

Edit--

I am trying to get row 2 and 3 of column 1 part. it begins with "I." and continues with "III." I initially tried to achieve that by setting different ol attribute class for each 2 cells:

```
<td class=cell1>
    <ol class=r2c1>
        <li>ol1 - item1</li>
    </ol>
</td>
<td class=cell2>row2 col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=cell3>
    <ol class = r3c1>
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li>ol1 - item3</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

css:

```
ol.r2c1{
    type: "I";
}
ol.r3c1{
    type: "I";
    start: "3";
}
```

(Which is incorrect since type and start both are not css attributes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` and `start` are not CSS properties. Dealing with [counters in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) is a bit complex, as you have to do everything manually:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: mycounter 2; /* whenever we see `<ol>`, `mycounter` is set to 2 */
}

li {
  list-style: none;  /* disable the default counter */
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: mycounter; /* whenever we see <li>, we increment `mycounter` by 1 */
  content: counter(mycounter, lower-roman) ". "; /* and display it before the <li> */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>number three</li>
  <li>number four</li>
</ol>
```

EDIT:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.r2c1 {
  counter-reset: c1counter;
}
.r3c1 {
  counter-reset: c1counter 2;
}

tr > td:first-child li::before {
  counter-increment: c1counter; /* whenever we see <li>, we increment `mycounter` by 1 */
  content: counter(c1counter, lower-roman) ". "; /* and display it before the <li> */
}

.cell1 { background: #fcdffe; }
.cell2 { background: #c4fdb8; }
.cell3 { background: #ffffff; }
.cell4 { background: #ffffc1; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">
      <ol class="r2c1">
        <li>ol1 - item1</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="cell2">row2 col2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell3">
      <ol class="r3c1">
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li>ol1 - item3</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="cell4">row3 col2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one following question: if I have multiple ordered list that should continue in different cells of the table(for example, at [row 1 col 1] I have one li of ol numbered 1, and at [row 2 col 1] I have other 2 li of same ol that should continue from 2), this method won't work since it edits the whole ol to start from number 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand the description. Please edit your question with the HTML you are describing, and what output you are expecting. But in general if you expect the lists to continue from when the last one stopped, you can be more selective when you reset the counter.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not doing this with HTML `<ol start="3">`, but with CSS? As I said, it's easier with HTML.

Comment: Well this is part of given assignment tbh.. and it has "All style need to be entered in an external CSS" condition. So now I am not sure if html attribute "start" is a kind of style. If it's sorted as style, then I have to modify it as what you suggested. but also it's pretty introductory class, so I am really not sure if I should touch that counters, as it wasn't introduced.

Comment: HTML attribute `start` is not style, since (as you see) it doesn't exist in CSS - even though you can muddle through with CSS counters to do the same thing. CSS counters are pretty advanced topic though. I'd say things like `<div style="color: red">` are style that you are prohibited from. But look at my edit anyway.

Comment: Thank you! your edit helped me to understand counter a bit better. Since it looks quite advanced(for ex: "tr > td:first-child li::before" such way of defining css was not even mentioned), I would go for using "start" attribute tho.. but thanks a lot!

Comment: On this snippet, plain `li` would work; but it would also affect the `<li>` elements in the second column as well, once you introduce them. Thus, I wanted to restrict them only to `<li>` elements on the first column. You could do something similar by having a class for first column, and writing `.c1 li`. Indeed, having `<tr class="r1 c1">` is much easier to work with than `<tr class="r1c1">`, as you can query them separately or together as you please. (You actually don't even need classes, as you can do this with `tr:nth-child` and `td:nth-child`, but that's even more advanced).

Answer (score 0):

`type` and `start` is HTML attributes, not CSS styles.

You can use `list-style-type: upper-roman` instead of HTML attribute. But, for `start` there is no substitute in CSS.

```
<td class=cell3>
    <ol class="r3c1" start="3">
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li>ol1 - item3</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
ol.r3c1{
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knfswo42/

[list-style-type documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

Comment: "But, for `start` there is no substitute in CSS." - Not quite true.

Comment: @Amadan: You can hardcode all the possible values of start and account for every single one of them, but until level 3 attr() is implemented there is no way to map this value dynamically to the counter-reset property.

Comment: @BoltClock: Dynamically? No. But OP was trying for a static value: `start: "3"`

Comment: @Amadan: *If 3 is all they will ever need*, then hardcoding is easy - you only need one value.

Comment: Thank you! this cleared my question about type. For starting value though, I did not describe what I actually need to do in detail at my original question, because it will get long and messy. Actually it's not that I just want to "start from 3," I want to connect two separate ol(placed in different cell of table) to continue. Anyway I got the answers desired. Thanks!

Comment: @Amadan: See? It's almost never as simple as starting from 3.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol.r3c1{
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    color: red;
}
p{
    color: black;
}

ol.r2{
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<td class=cell3> 
    <ol class="r2" start="3">
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li><p>Color Black</p></li>
    </ol>
</td>
--------------------------------------
<td class=cell3> 
    <ol class="r3c1">
        <li>ol1 - item2</li>
        <li><p>Color Black</p></li>
    </ol>
</td>
-------------------------------------
```